# Correct way to add fields to a model on django

Tags: python, django, model, migration

I have a User model and i want to add a new field to the user, in the database and in the user form. i have looked online many differente ways to do this but i want to know what is the *"correct"* way to do it. Specially the correct way to create migrations.

Django Version: (1,10,0,u'final',1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got what you're looking for but let's say you want to add a "Status" field to your User model, and then have it in the Admin panel so you can interact with it (update, change, etc...).

in models.py - we are creating a Profile class which will be linked to a User and then a status to be added to a user:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    " A profile added User """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # so to link the profile to a user
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # a field status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

in admin.py - we are integrating the newly created Profile to the user

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

# And then we unregister the User class and register the two updated ones
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**Don't forget to run `/manage.py makemigrations` and then `/manage.py migrate` to update the database.**

Let me know if that answer your question.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what i was looking for